# Remove alphabets and Insert numbers only

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I have table in this i am using id as from number but my from numbers are alphanumeric and i dont want to use a id with alphanumeric value, there any PHP/Mysql function or script for do like this or there is any way to insert data in mysql by removing alphabat
for example
id
1
2
3

FormNo
aaa1
aaa2

i just want when some one fill form number like aaa3 this will be store in database only 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$str= 'aaa1';
$str = preg_replace("/[^0-9,.]/", "", $str);

//then store $str in DB
```

Answer (score 0):

here is your answer...

`<?php
    $str= 'aaa1';
    echo preg_replace("/[^0-9,.]/", "", $str);
?>`

Comment: This will throw an error. `$str = 'aaa1';` <- needs quotes.

Comment: @NishantSolanki this will be error **Notice: Use of undefined constant aaa1 - assumed 'aaa1'**

Comment: You have notices turned off then. This __will__ throw an error on E_ALL.

Comment: @NishantSolanki i am using 5.5 this what i recieved as error ^_*

Answer (score 0):

Please type this code, i hope it would be work for yoy

```
<?php $str= 'aaa1'; 
echo preg_filter("/[^\d]/i", "", $str); 
?>
```